# Is defining private to public guaranteed to keep the class's structure?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer

I have a special cpp file, that I want it to have access to everything.
I'm considering defining:

```
#define private public
```

In the beginning of the file and than including everything that I need.

Is it guaranteed to work, or can the compiler change the structure of the class in that case?

I'm not asking whether it's smart, or pretty (which obviously is not), only whether it will work.

Specifically I'm using VS2013.

Comment: this is a very bad idea!

Comment: If you're using the standard library, this define would give undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielA.White I absolutely agree. Sometimes this is used as a hack, to enable testing code to access class intrinsics.

Comment: "**[class.mem]/13** Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (Clause 11)." So yes, in theory changing access control may change binary layout of the class. Also, giving two different definitions to the same class in different parts of the programs is a violation of One Definition Rule, whereupon the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: In practice, with MSVC you may have difficulty linking your program. I'm pretty sure MSVC encodes member access into mangled name.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a world of pain if you attempt this. Igor's comments essential  answer the question - the binary layout of class could change, and because you are violating the ODR, the behavior is undefined. Although not guaranteed, MSVC will likely exhibit problems in practice, depending on how the modified classes are used.

A much better way to achieve this is to make a new class that is a friend of any class you may need private access to. This class can be defined only in your one cpp file. It's a lot more work, but tracking down random crashes because of UB takes a really long time.